# Is this a conflict in RoR tutorial test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, railstutorial.org

Im following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial.

In his Listing 9.42, he shows a test for links to delete users, on index page.Ž
Test is supposed to make sure that user with `admin: true` attribute sees `delete` links on user's index page (user's listing page).

Also, admin (first user) is not supposed to see a link to delete himself.

Test code goes as follows:

> ```
> describe "delete links" do
> ```

```
  it { should_not have_link('delete') }

  describe "as an admin user" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
    before do
      sign_in admin
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
    it "should be able to delete another user" do
      expect do
        click_link('delete', match: :first)
      end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end
    it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
  end
end
```

What puzzles me about this code is this:
it seems only logical to me that the first `it` clause in the describe block
which mentions path to User.first (which is admin here, cause admin is first in database)
conflicts with the third `it` clause in the describe block, which requires
that link to admin's delete doesn't exist.

Am I missing something here?

I didnt even run the thing yet, but it seems to me it has to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that it is shown in your question but the first `it` block has no conflict as the first user was created above this code.

`let(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}`.

The third it block refers to when the admin is signed it should not have a delete button for itself.

here is the full spec for `#index`:

```
subject { page }

describe "index" do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } #First User Created Here 

  before do
    sign_in user
    visit users_path
  end

  it { should have_title('All users') }
  it { should have_content('All users') }

  describe "pagination" do
    .
    .
    .
  end

  describe "delete links" do

    it { should_not have_link('delete') }

    describe "as an admin user" do
      let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) } #Admin Created here
      before do
        sign_in admin
        visit users_path
      end

      it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
      it "should be able to delete another user" do
        expect do
          click_link('delete', match: :first)
        end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
      end
      it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

certainly you should run it to figure out what the actual case. As per my understanding, this depends on how your `database` cleaner works, if it clean database on every run test which is common case then the above specs will pass.